# Passthrough <filname>.png to <filename>8.png if IE<=6 and <filename>8.png exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, png

I just found out that by converting PNG32 to PNG8 via Photoshop will fix the PNG transparency bug in IE<=6.

So I had this thought that instead of serving PNG32 to all browser, why not serve PNG8 if the client is using IE<=6.

I'm not really an expert when it comes to htaccess/httpd directives so I'm here for help.

The title is the psuedocode itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but I think it should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/4.0\ \(compatible;\ MSIE\ [1-6]\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)(\.png)$
RewriteCond %18%2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.png$ $18.png [L,QSA]
```

The first line  turns  mod_rewrite on (and can be omitted if you've already done that).
The second does the IE <= 6 filter.
The third is mainly to split the filename for the fourth line, which checks to see if <filename>8.png exists.  The fifth line actually does the redirect.

Comment: i'll give feedback as soon as i run this delicious script

Comment: In what way did it fail?  Try using only the HTTP_USER_AGENT condition, or only the REQUEST_FILENAME conditions, to see which one is wrong.

Comment: I've added backslashes before the spaces in the IE regex; see if that works better.

Comment: yey, It actually works! I kept on clearing IE's cache but only a browser restart will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.png$ /$18.png [L,QSA]
```

Should work.

Comment: This doesn't check for browser version IE<=6, does it?

Comment: I understand that that directive forwards some.png to some8.png, but does it handle IE browser detection too. Oh, I also forgot the check if the file exists too.

Comment: It does not check for IE<=6, nor does it check whether the file exists.

Comment: Use cjm's .htaccess. He read the question more carefully I guess... Sorry